# Divide two integer and got wrong ouput using BEANSHELL Library

Tags: android, beanshell

I am using to "Beanshell" library (http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshmanual.html)  for mathematical expression. it works good. but if i divide two integer like

```
4/2 = 2 //it ok
5/2=2  // it should be 2.5
```

may be problem is on Library. please expert have a look.

Comment: It's integer division (with quotient and remainder: 5 == 2 * 2 + 1); try 5.0/2.0 instead

Comment: thx i did it and work but other calculation is not working now. parseexception got

Answer (score 1):

Since Beanshell is based on Java, it largely uses the same math operations. The '/' operator will perform integer division, throwing away any fractional part, if both of the operands are integers. So `5 / 2` will be 2, while `5.0 / 2`  or  `5 / 2.0` will be 2.5.

Comment: thx , it works for that. but now not working for other calculation. got parse excetion